# Keep fixed active requests in Spring WebClient

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a Spring Boot application that reads messages from RabbitMQ (via Spring AMQP `@RabbitListner`). These messages contain URLs that I need to request, parse the response and save to DB.

I make request to these URLs through proxy (ScraperAPI) that permits up to 50 concurrent requests.

The response from this proxy takes ~30 seconds that's why for the best performance of my service I need to always keep 50 active requests.

For now I have following code:

**RabbitMQ Message**

```
public class UrlToParse{
    private String propertyUrl;
    private String zillowUrl;
}
```

**RabbitMQ Listener**

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "urls.queue"})
public void consumeUrls(UrlsToParse urls) {
    parserManager.parseUrls(urls.getUrlsToParse());
}
```

**Parser Manager**

```
    public void parseUrls(List<UrlToParse> urls) {
        Flux.fromIterable(stream)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .flatMap(this::parse)
            .flatMap(url -> Mono.just(urlsRepository.save(url)))
            .subscribe();
    }

    private Mono<ParsedUrl> parse(UrlToParse url) {
        return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(url.getUrl())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(s -> Mono.just(buildParsedUrl(s)));
    }
```

I tried to add `.delayElements()`, `.limitRate()` and `Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer()` but it looks more like hard-coded  solution and won't work if message amount grows.

In non-reactive programming solution for this task sounds like BlockingQueue. But I'm wondering is there any mechanisms to make it Reactive?

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE

I implemented this in the following way:

1. Use `.flatMap(this::parse, 50)` to limit concurrency in flatMap
2. Call `.block()` at the end of Flux. This was needed to send acknowledgment to RabbitMQ only once all URLs are were processed. Otherwise, acknowledgment is sent immediately and new messages were consumed. In this way I get 10 messages being processed with 50 concurrent calls = 500 concurrent calls.

For more reactive approach you can look into Reactor RabbitMQ but unfortunately I didn't have time for this

### UPDATE 2

Instead of using Reactor RabbitMQ you can manually poll for messages in `Flux.generate()` method along with `flatMap(function, concurrency)` to control the back-pressure:

```
Flux.generate((SynchronousSink<UrlToParse> synchronousSink) -> {
                    UrlToParse urls = amqpTemplate.receiveAndConvert(queueName, UrlToParse.class);
                    if (urls != null) {
                        synchronousSink.next(urls);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `.flatMap(this::parse, 50)` to limit you to 50 concurrent requests as part of your flatmap call?

Comment: You can add a second argument "max concurrency" to the flatmap operation. This is an integer to tell how many actions can be started concurrzntly at most.

Comment: @MichaelBerry @amanin Thanks, it works. But then I faced with another problem - processing goes asynchronous that's why acknowledgement to RabbitMQ sends right after the message was consumed. Limit of 50 in `flatMap` is applied for each message that's why when next message consumes there're 100 concurrent requests and it failing again.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347590/correct-way-of-using-spring-webclient-in-spring-amqp. I have similar use case but having issue where occasionally one or more rabbitmq consumers just stop with unack messages. Could you help advise?