# Parallel Flux blocking call

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

My application set up is mentioned as part of issue# [Correct way of using spring webclient in spring amqp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71347590/correct-way-of-using-spring-webclient-in-spring-amqp)
where I am trying to use Spring webclient to make API calls in Spring AMQP rabbit MQ consumer threads.
Issue seems to be that parallel flux blocking call just stalls or takes a very long time after first few requests are fired.

To simulate this, I did below minimalistic set up -

Dependencies used

```
Spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-webflux
reactor-netty 0.9.14.RELEASE
```

As mentioned in the other linked issue, below is configuration for webclient -

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider
.builder("fixed")
.lifo()
.pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(200000))
.maxConnections(100)
.pendingAcquireMaxCount(3000)
.maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(290000))
.build();

HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider);
client.tcpConfiguration(<<connection timeout, read timeout, write timeout is set here....>>);

Webclient.Builder builder = 
Webclient.builder().baseUrl(<<base URL>>).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client));

return builder.build();
}
```

Below is @Service class with parallel flux webclient calls -

```
@Service
public class FluxtestService {

public Flux<Response> getFlux(List<Request> reqList) {
  return Flux
.fromIterable(reqList)
.parallel()
.runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
.flatMap(s -> {
  return webClient
         .method(POST)
         .uri(<<downstream url>>)
         .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(s))
         .exchange()
         .flatMap(response -> {
            if(response.statusCode().isError()){
               return Mono.just(new Response());
            }
            return response.bodyToMono(Response.class);
         }) 
        }).sequential();
}
}
}
```

To simulate Spring AMQP rabbit mq consumer/listener, I created below @RestController -

```
@RestController
public class FluxTestController

@Autowired
private FluxtestService service;

@PostMapping("/fluxtest")
public List<Response> getFlux (List<Request> reqlist) {
return service.getFlux(reqlist).collectList().block();
}
```

I tried firing requests from jmeter with around 15 threads. First few set of requests are processed very quickly. While requests are being served, I can see below set of logs in log file -

```
Channel cleaned, now 32 active connections and 68 inactive connections
```

Once I submit more set of requests, the active connections keeps increasing till it reaches max configured 100. I don't see it decreasing at all. Till this point, response time is ok.

But any subsequent requests start taking very long time. Also I don't see the active connections reducing much at all even though there are no requests being fired.

Also after some time, I see below exceptions -

```
reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquireTimeoutException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 200000 ms
```

This probably shows that the downstream connection is not being released. Please help advise on this issue and possible fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems issue was because the underlying connection was not being properly released in case webclient downstream call responded with error status. While using "exchange" with "webclient", it seems we need to ensure that the response is properly released; else it can lead to connections leak. Below are the changes that seemed to fix this issue -

Replace

```
.flatMap(response -> {
   if(response.statusCode().isError()) {
     return Mono.just(new Response());
   }
   return response.bodyToMono(Response.class);
})
```

with

```
.flatMap(response -> {
   if(response.statusCode().isError()) {
     response.releaseBody().thenReturn(Mono.just(new Response()));
   }
   return response.bodyToMono(Response.class);
})
```